# Import from the root of the repository when running a jupyter notebook

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, pythonpath, cd

I have a repository with the following setup:

```
│
└───foo_lib
│   │   bar.py
│   
└───notebooks
    │   my_notebook.ipynb
```

So basically I have some common python code in `foo_lib` and some notebook in `notebooks`

In `my_notebook` I want to use the code from `foo_lib`. So I do:

```
from foo_lib import bar
```

But that doesn't work because the root of the repo isn't in my python path when the notebook is executed.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e2c421feccf4> in <module>
----> 1 from foo_lib import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo_lib'
```

The hack I've been using is to put `%cd ..` in the first cell. Then the working directory is the root of the repo and I can import fine. But it's not idempotent, so if I run the cell more than once, imports break again.

I found an idempotent solution. I can use `globals()["_dh"][0]` which points to the directory containing the notebook, when running in jupyter:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.join(globals()["_dh"][0], ".."))
```

Unfortuantely, this doesn't work when I run my notebook programatically using `nbconvert`:

```
import json

import nbconvert
import nbformat


def run_notebook():
    ep = nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor()
    with open("notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb") as fp:
        nb = nbformat.read(fp, as_version=4)
    nb, resources = ep.preprocess(nb)
    print(json.dumps(nb, indent=2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_notebook()
```

When I run this script from the root of the repository, `globals()["_dh"][0]` points to the root of the repository

So I'm looking for a solution to this import problem that:

- is idempotent
- works when executing from the browser/jupyter
- works when executing using nbconvert
- is short: I would have to copy paste the code in every notebook (since before that code runs, I can't do imports).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that the local repository code and be added to the site-package by calling:

```
pip install -e .
```